# Modal dialog boxes

Tags: jquery, forms, dialog, modal-dialog

How to dynamically change the content of a dialog box.

I have a table that has all user information.For every record user email is made the hyperlink. When user clicks on any of the email, dialog has to open with the details of the clicked record. How do we do that? Please guide me.

Regards,
Sitaram

Comment: Where is the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax! I snubbed out most of the methods, but this should get you in motion.

```
$('.email_link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $this.data('email_identifier');
    data = doSomeAjaxCallWithThisUniqueId(id); //have some ajax call to get you email based data
    openModal()  //create your modal.
    $(.modal-body).html(data);  // then after, populate it.
})
```